# Find when a hard disk was first installed

Tags: hard-disk, aix

What's the command in AIX to find the first time a given hard disk was installed?

Answer (score 2):

I have no AIX running nearby, but have you tried `lscfg -vl <devicename>` perhaps with an additional `-p` to get the platform specific informations too ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the command to view a hard disk install time:

```
ls -l /dev/hdisk
```

Comment: I don't have a `/dev/hdisk`, but most if not all `/dev` entries have creation times of whenever udev created them, which is generally at boot time. Your notion of "hard disk installed time" doesn't make much sense; the closest you might be able to get is "first mount time"